# animating ImageButton in android?

Tags: android, animation, imagebutton

I am really new to animations in android (and pretty much anything else). Is there a way to animate an ImageButton? I just want to rotate the button for sometimes. Thats all. Any help ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this code snippet.

**rotate.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<rotate

    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:toDegrees="360"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="0"
    android:duration="1000" />

</set>
```

in java file

```
ImageButton imgbt = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.your_id);
Animation ranim = (Animation)AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.rotate);
imgbt.setAnimation(ranim);
```

Comment: received an `java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.animation.AnimationSet`  error on this line : `        RotateAnimation ranim = (RotateAnimation)AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.rotate);`

Comment: any help on this ? I am totally newbie with animations.. :(

Comment: I think the line should use Animation instead of RotateAnimation.

Comment: also, what to do if I want the cicrcular imagebutton to rotate around itself ?

Comment: this works fine if the padding for the imagebutton is uniform. thanks.

Answer (score 7):

**rotate.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:toDegrees="360" />
```

**Java Code :**

```
RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = (RotateAnimation) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.rotate);
view.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
```